# How can I add postgresql to an existing dockerfile?

Tags: c#, postgresql, docker, asp.net-core, visual-studio-2019

I am working on an ASP.NET Core API project with docker support.
I was hoping I could add postgresql or mysql to my dockerfile and have it just work. Now, I don't have much experience with docker at all however I am happy with what it does and how it works (especially that my pc doesn't get cluttered with random programs that I don't need except for one project).

I have tried the example from https://docs.docker.com/engine/examples/postgresql_service/ 
However it doesn't really look like it should work to me and I like to know how my stuff works. So even if it works properly I'd rather have a solution where it looks more like this:

```
FROM postgresql:11.5
EXPOSE 5432
ENV <add password environment variable here>
```

The dockerfile I have before adding postgresql is

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:2.2-stretch-slim AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:2.2-stretch AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["ModOs__Api/ModOs__Api.csproj", "ModOs__Api/"]
RUN dotnet restore "ModOs__Api/ModOs__Api.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/ModOs__Api"
RUN dotnet build "ModOs__Api.csproj" -c Release -o /app

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "ModOs__Api.csproj" -c Release -o /app

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app .

ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "ModOs__Api.dll"]
```

When the postgres is added I'd like to simply be able to connect to it at the URL localhost:5432 in the c# code. Also, if possible it would be awesome if I can view the databases in my browser (However, if this makes things 10x more complicated please don't waste time on it).

What is the best or a great way of doing this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You almost always run a database as a separate container, possibly using a tool like Docker Compose to orchestrate them.  The database's hostname is never `localhost` in Docker.  The Docker documentation includes a [Compose and ASP.NET Core with SQL Server](https://docs.docker.com/compose/aspnet-mssql-compose/) sample application that may be a reasonable starting point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't. Although possible, I would advice against doing it like this. The philosophy with Docker is that each service runs in it's *own* container. If you follow this paradigm, things will be much easier for you. On the upside, there is a beaten path for this making this comfortable. Check out this simple [docker compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/) file for example

```
version: '3'
services:
  web:
    build: .
    ports:
      - "80:80"
  postgres:
    image: "postgres:9.6"
```

Instead of connecting to `localhost:5432` you connect to `postgres:5432`.

Spin everything up with `docker-compose up`

Comment: Thanks mate! However, since I am using Visual studio for this project(I don't know if this is the actual cause) it doesn't work right of the bat. To get it working you click on the project that you want to add docker-compose to >Add>Container Orchestrator support then select docker-compose and there you go. add   `postgres:
    image: "postgres:9.6"` and done (notice the 9.6 :) )

Comment: Ops, updated the answer now. Glad it was so easy in Visual Studio. Sweet.